# How do i access user variable in other node js files?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

UserSchema is created and saved in collection in mongod

I am not able to access user var in other files

How do i access it in other js files.

my Register.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/*Create new Schema for Users*/
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
});

var user = mongoose.model('Users',userSchema);
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mongoose model by:

```
var Users = mongoose.model('Users');
```

then use `Users` in your other js files